# Using Array in typescript

Tags: angular

I have checkbox in formular, and I want to store data in database with atribut with more IDs. So in my opinion, the best way is to use type Array to good later working with entered IDs.
But in Angular I have function addMatch in matchs.service.ts and there I have error:

```
Argument of type 'Player[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
  Type 'Player[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Here is function, where I have problem, where Player is model:

```
  addMatch(dateOfMatch: Date,
    playersPlayed: Array<Player>) {
    const matchData = new FormData();
    matchData.append("dateOfMatch", dateOfMatch.toString());
    matchData.append("playersPlayed", playersPlayed);

    this.http
      .post<{ message: string; match: Match }>(
        "http://localhost:3000/api/matchs",
        matchData
      )
      .subscribe(responseData => {
        this.router.navigate(["/"]);
      });
  }
```

In my HTML, where I get data from user is here:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select formControlName="playersPlayed" placeholder="Players" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let player of players" [value]="player.id">{{player.name}} {{player.surename}} ({{player.teamName}})</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
   <mat-error *ngIf="form.get('playersPlayed').invalid">Please enter a players who played.</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

What I do wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The error tells you what is wrong and where. You're trying to call `matchData.append("playersPlayed", playersPlayed)`. `playersPlayed`is of type `Player[]`. But this method expects a string or a Blob. Does your backend really expect a multipart/form-data body? Or does it expect JSON. If it expects JSON, then send a JavaScript object with the expected structure, not a FormData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From FormData documentation about append function's value parameter:

> This can be a USVString or Blob (including subclasses such as File).

Source: [FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append)

So I assume in your case the string option will be the correct one. I would try to stringify the Player array, I guess this could work:

```
matchData.append("playersPlayed", JSON.stringify(playersPlayed));
```